# Question about/with particles

Tags: particles

this is my first question on this site and i going to use romaji because i didnt configured my keyboard. So... i use a book that dont have answers-key, then i dont have sure if i doing right.

> [ですから]{Desukara}、[鈴木]{Suzuki}さん{san}　[は]{wa}　[６]{roku}[時]{ji}[半]{han}　**[に]{ni}**　[起]{o}[きます]{kimasu}。
>
> [会社]{kaisha} **[へ]{e}** [７]{shichi}[時]{ji}[１５]{juugo}[分]{hun} **[に]{ni}** [行]{i}[きます]{kimasu}。

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are the two sentences in that order?

Comment: Yep, is a fragment of routine of a boy

Comment: How can this question can up vote when there is no question? What is the question?

Comment: Well, you can see the context "then i dont have sure if i doing right", but i will clarify, i dont have sure if the particles used is the right ones for the case.

Answer (score 3):

All of the particles have been selected correctly.

「(Person/Thing) + **は**～～」: topic marker

「(Specific Time) + **に**～～」: time marker

「(Place) + **へ**～～」: direction marker

Comment: I just pulled out my Japanese I textbook and it confirms this as well.